# Are there Galois covers of curves branched at 1 point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a finite group, not necessarily abelian. Is there any smooth algebraic curve $C$, with an action of $G$ on $C$, such that the natural quotient map $C \to C/G$ is branched at precisely one point?

I know that this cannot happen when $G$ is abelian, but what about the general case?

(EDIT: a branch point is the image in $C/G$ of a ramification point)

Comment: Interesting question! Why can't it happen if $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Yes it can if $G$ is a center-free group.